# iOS - select images based on album

Tags: ios, photos, sample

I have gone through several tutorials trying to get this through my thick skull with little luck.  I am trying to allow users to select a photo album and be able to iterate through the photos in it.  I have code going now to list the names of the various photo albums, but actually finding and selecting images from these using what I've found about the ALAssetsLibrary is driving me insane.

Looking for some direction or a pointer to a piece of sample code that does this on iOS5+, if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ELCImagePickerController`](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) project which shows both how to get the albums and how to get the images inside each album.